# is it possible to make the html children div element width not greater than than the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html div called `pdfContainer` that shows pdf content in webpage. The pdf rend html look like this:

```
<div id="pdfContainer" className={styles.previewBody} onScroll={(e) => handlePdfScroll(e)}>
            <Document options={options}
                file={curPdfUrl}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
                {renderPages(numPages)}
            </Document>
</div>
```

this is the previewBody css define:

```
.previewBody {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

this is how to render the pdf pages:

```
const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
        if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
        const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPageNum; i++) {
            tagList.push(
                <Page key={i}
                    className={styles.pdfPage}
                    scale={projAttribute.pdfScale}
                    onLoad={handlePageChange}
                    canvasRef={(element) => updateRefArray(i, element)}
                    onChange={handlePageChange}
                    onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
                    pageNumber={i} >
                    {curPdfPosition && viewport ? <Highlight position={curPdfPosition}
                        pageNumber={i}
                        viewport={viewport}></Highlight> : <div></div>}
                </Page>
            );
        }
        return tagList;
    }
```

this is the pdfPage define:

```
.pdfPage {
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Now I am facing the issue that the Document page's width will greater than the parent element `pdfContainer`.

[image]

what should I do to let the children pdf page not greater than the parent? BTW, the `pdfContainer` is draggale enabled by left/right, the `pdfContainer` width will change when user drag the column to left or right.

Comment: Get a horizontal scrollbar on the container: `.pdfContainer { overflow-x: auto; }`?

Comment: I tried to tweak the . previewBody to `.previewBody {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}` still could not fixed this issue @the Hutt.

Comment: I see. A minimum reproducible would be helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of overflow-x and set `max-width: 100%` on the page:

```css
.content {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.previewBody {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.pdfPage {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="previewBody">
    <Document>
      <Page class="pdfPage">
        <p>
          Page 1 Page long long text lorem ipsum text long text. Some long long text text text. Very long text.
        </p>
      </Page>
      <Page class="pdfPage">
        <p>
          Page 2. Page long long text lorem ipsum text long text. Some long long text text text. Very long text.
        </p>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  </div>
</div>
```